# How to make multiple copies of a file using Ant?

Tags: ant

I have a file that I want to make 100 copies of. I was looking at the ANT api and I didn't see anything that explicitly made multiple copies of a file. There's a touch feature to create new files and a "copy" to move a file from one folder to another. Any thoughts on how I should go about doing this?

Comment: What kind of copy ? Copy foobar.ext to dir1/foobar.ext ... dir100/foobar.ext or copy foobar.ext to some/path/foobar1.ext ... foobar100.ext ? More details please.

Answer (score 0):

The ant copy task is not for moving files, it does copy. If you use the dir attribute it's going to copy the file to a specific directory not changing the name. Using the tofile attribute specifies a named file where the content goes, and that should differ from the original.

If you want to copy one file multiple times you either have to repeat the copy task as often as you need it or try something with ant-contribs for task so you can interate over a list of multiple locations where you want to copy it.

The problem you'll be running in is that properties are immutable and therefor it will getting difficult to give the files a generic name (e.g. myfile1.txt to myfile100.txt).

Probably the fastest way will be to write a custom ant task that let's you generate the files exactly by your needs. Copying a file isn't that hard, but getting it to work "the ant way" will be!